# PHP Category Menu (mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, menu

This is probably an easy fix - but I've been getting A LOT of issues trying to set this up. Basically I'm trying to create a category menu for an article page. The "list" has each category and underneath that list would be each article with the same attribute.

I have two tables set up one that holds all the categories and the other which holds the news posts. Yet for some reason...only the first post shows up - not the latter...

For example:

African Animals

**Lion**

**Elephant**

Farm Animals

**Pig**

```
<?php
    $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles_category');
        while($row = $STH->fetch()) { 
            echo "<li>\n";
            echo "<a href='' class='nav-top-item'>". $row['category'] ."</a>\n";
            echo "<ul>\n";
            $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category="'. $row['category'] .'"');
                    while($row = $STH->fetch()) { 
                        echo "<li><a href='articles/article?id=". $row['id'] ."'>". $row['title'] ."</a></li>\n";
                    }
            echo "</ul>\n";
            echo "</li>\n";
            }   
?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading the following blog about menu's: http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/317/formatting-a-multi-level-menu-using-only-one-query.html.
You can do this a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$STH_2 = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles ...'
while($row_2 = $STH_2->fetch()) {
   echo "<li><a href='articles/article?id=". $row_2['id'] ."'>". $row_2['title'] ."</a></li>\n";
}
```

You are loading subcategory to same array $STH, change name, and second while should have different name too -> $row_2 will help

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `$STH` variable in the inner loop.

Change:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category ...
```

To:

```
$STH2 = ...
    while($row = $STH2->fetch()) {
```

Comment: I tried this (oddly enough the exact same naming convention)- yet for some reason the page just stopped working. Any ideas?

Comment: different name should apply not only to $STH, to row also

Comment: @bensiu, I'm not sure that is actually necessary. Look at how the variable is used.

Comment: looks like you are right, however it somehow did not work for @keiran, and it nice to enforce good variable naming practice -> when code extend 2 months later it could be imposible to detect (remember)

Answer (score 1):

You may **not** use the same identifier for two operations which shall be different (which is happening in your case with `$STH`.
Because of doing that, you are overwritting `$STH` in the inner scope and that propagates to the outside loop condition.

You should change the variable name and you should also consider changing it to a more descriptive name : )

Comment: ISTH = Inner Statement Handle ? :)